# Extract a part of string between multiple delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with value as '/1064_MyHoldings/ONLINE/Adhoc/Rpt_CompanyCodeElig'

Now, my requirement is to extract every value which is there between the delimeters; '1064 MyHoldings', 'ONLINE', 'Adhoc' etc?

I tried the below code, but it is only taking '1064 MyHoldings'. But I need the other values as well
Can someone please help me here?

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '/1064_MyHoldings/ONLINE/Adhoc/Rpt_CompanyCodeElig' AS Path
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN Path LIKE '%/%/%' THEN
    SUBSTRING(Path,
              CHARINDEX('/', Path) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('/', Path, CHARINDEX('/', Path) + 1) - CHARINDEX('/', Path) - 1)
         ELSE 'NA' END AS first_component
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are 2 quite different products...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select s.value
from t cross apply
     string_split(path, '/') s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for recursive search using CTE and split the strings.

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '/1064_MyHoldings/ONLINE/Adhoc/Rpt_CompanyCodeElig' AS Path
),
cte_splitTable as
(
SELECT value as val, 1 as lvl
from yourTable
cross apply 
string_split(Path,'_')
UNION ALL
SELECT t.value as val, lvl+1 as lvl
from cte_splitTable as c
cross apply
string_split(c.val,'/') as t
where CHARINDEX('/',val) > 0
)
select *  from cte_splitTable
where PATINDEX('%[_/]%',val) = 0 and len(val) > 0
```

```
+-----------------+
|       val       |
+-----------------+
| CompanyCodeElig |
| MyHoldings      |
| ONLINE          |
| Adhoc           |
| Rpt             |
| 1064            |
+-----------------+
```